# Spring MVC rollback with custom message

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I have a Spring MVC service method to execute save() and update() - two operations.

After save() is successfully executed, if I find the user to update does not exist, I will manually throw a new RuntimeExceotion() to rollback the save operation. In this case, how could I return the Error Message("can't find the user") to browser side?

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
public Map<String,Object> service(){
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    //1. save user
    User user = getUser();
    this.save(user);

    //2. try to update another
    String anotherUserId = "anUserId";
    User anUser = this.getById(anotherUserId);
    if(anUser != null){
        anUser.setName("newName");
        this.update(anUser);
        map.put("status",true);
    }else{
        //logical error
        map.put("status",false);
        map.put("err_msg","cant find the user for update");        

        //triger rollback(rollback save user)
        throw new RuntimeException("update user error");
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you wrap your errors in an Object and pass that to the Exception while throwing it.

Later at the controller/request-response handler layer, get the Error object from the Exception and pass that to UI layer.

```
Class CustomException extends Exception {

    Map<String,Object> errorMap;

    public CustomException(String errorMsg, Map errorMap)
    {
        super(errorMsg);
        this.errorMap = errorMap;
    }
    public CustomException(Throwable cause){
        super(cause);
    }

    public CustomException(String message ,Throwable cause){
        super(message,cause);
    }
}
```

While Throwing the exception:

```
throw new CustomException("Can not find the user", map);
```

In the Controller End, Catch this exception and extract the ErrorMap which contains your data.
Wrap/Convert this Object and pass it to UI/Browser.

Comment: Really appreciate! It works perfect, I did't think about doing something after throw an exception to SpringTransactional.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `CustomException` class which contain your error msg.

you can send back error msg to your client. For that you can make your service which return type would be Object that's why it can send an `Map` or `ErrorMessage`.

`CustomException` class looks something like that:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception implements Serializable {

    public CustomException(String errorMsg)
    {
        super(errorMsg);
    }
    public CustomException(Throwable cause){
        super(cause);
    }

    public CustomException(String message ,Throwable cause){
        super(message,cause);
    }
}
```

you can use this by:

```
throw new CustomException("Can not find the user");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, maybe I'm not express well. When I throw the Exception (RuntimeException  or  like your said CustomException), Spring MVC will take over this, and do rollback operation, and my "return obj;" wont be execute. 
If I throw an exception, browser side(ajax Call), how to get the Object?

Comment: You can make your object serializable for sending over the network.
`public class CustomException extends Exception implements Serializable{}`

Comment: I solve the problem followed @Bandi Kishore 's advice, in controller method, try{service();}catch(CustomException e){map = e.getErrorMap();}.
By try-catch block, after SpringTransactional rollback finished, will throw this exception to my controller method. Then I can continue error msg handle.